# Array.Includes not detecting an existing element

Tags: javascript

I fetch a JSON file with a node named `current_users`, my simple code is:

```
function hashCode(string) {
   // a simple algo that converts my string name to a unique ID
    var hash = 0, i, chr;
    if (string.length === 0) return hash;
    for (i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        chr   = string.charCodeAt(i);
        hash  = ((hash << 5) - hash) + chr;
    hash |= 0; // Convert to 32bit integer
   }
   return hash;
}

// fetched data
fetch("https://example.com/file.json").then(function(response) {
var currentUsers = response.current_users || [];
console.log('currentUsers', currentUsers); // prints [711904501]
var isKnown = false; // user is unknown by default
if (Array.isArray(currentUsers)) {
    isKnown = currentUsers.includes(hashCode(me)); // hashCode(me) = 711904501
    // log below prints a strange result: a valid array [711904501] false 711904501
    console.log('a valid array', currentUsers, isKnown, hashCode(me));
    if (isKnown) {
        unlockDoor(); // not reached, isKnown = false while it must be true
    }
}
});
```

Why `currentUsers.includes` does not return `true` although the simple one-element array includes the value `711904501` and both of them are integers?

If I run it this simple, it works:

```
var currentUsers = [711904501];
console.log(currentUsers.includes(711904501)); // true
```

I am very confused why I see different results. I can't sleep.

Comment: Check your assumptions—is it async (don’t rely on console log)?

Comment: I updated my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem after a deeper close, I miss understood the `fetch` function. The `.then` chain doesn't mean the request is finished. Another method inside should do it:

```
fetch('./api/some.json')
  .then(
    function(response) {
      if (response.status !== 200) {
        console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' +
          response.status);
        return;
      }

      // Examine the text in the response
      response.json().then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      });
    }
  )
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);
  });
```

Reference is here: [Introduction to fetch()](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch#fetch), that was completely unexpected!

Comment: From the source: The response of a fetch() request is a Stream object, which means that when we call the json() method, a Promise is returned since the reading of the stream will happen asynchronously.

Comment: I should have been more precise, but in the general use-case, you’re correct.